How does postgres allocate rows to workers and use memory in parallel queries?
I did 2 runs and was surprised by the memory use of the 2nd run. I thought i could half the memory use while taking double the processing time by halving max_parallel_workers_per_gather
Experiments were done on Aurora AWS but I believe this is a postgres concept.
Query plan: Subquery Scan -> WindowAgg -> Gather Merge -> Sort -> Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan -> Bitmap Index Scan
Run 1: work_mem = 4GB and max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8

Run 2：work_mem = 4GB and max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4

I noticed that in Run 1, each of 9 (8 parallel + leader) workers had 1.69 million rows.
In Run 2, each of 5 workers had about 3 million rows. This indicates that the total rows are being distributed evenly to workers + leader.
Questions
Best if answers could point to exact lines in the code (https://github.com/postgres/postgres). I have built postgres from source and am GDB debugging it in vs code but my C knowledge is not strong enough to trace. I'm using version 13 but anything newer should work too.

How is postgres allocating rows to workers and leader? Are workers pulling rows from some shared queue until exhaustion, or is some central node (eg. Gather Node) distributing rows to workers?
How do I predict roughly how much memory will be used? Can total
memory be predicted by number of rows * width + unknown small
overhead? This would allow setting sufficiently high work_mem to
avoid sorting on disk, determined by (rows * width + unknown small
overhead)/ max_parallel_workers_per_gather (*)
How is postgres intelligently splitting the 18GB free memory (AWS RDS term, probably just means RAM) evenly into workers without spilling to disk? Lowering work_mem to 2GB at 4 parallel workers does make it to sort on disk though.

(*) I've no idea how to set max_parallel_workers_per_gather in the first place. Experiments I done seem to indicate it's not the more workers the faster for overall speed. The only heuristic I have is parallel is faster than non-parallel, experimentally verified to be true up to some point.
I have read postgres wikis but the first link seems outdated and written for parallel CREATE INDEX, not for parallel queries. The second link doesn't mention anything on row allocation to workers.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_External_Sort
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Parallel_Internal_Sort

Likely locations of answer to question 1 in source:

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/executor/execParallel.c
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/executor/nodeGatherMerge.c
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/23c5a0e7d43bc925c6001538f04a458933a11fc1/src/backend/executor/execMain.c#L368 (sendTuples and count looks relevant)
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/executor/nodeBitmapHeapscan.c
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/executor/execScan.c

Possibly useful theory:

https://15721.courses.cs.cmu.edu/spring2024/notes/08-scheduling.pdf

